# How to add margin to SVG Circle's stroke for a simple donut

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to build a very simple donut chart.

Here's the working code :

```js
const countries = [
{'percent': 2,colour: 'red'},
{'percent': 28,colour: 'blue'},
{'percent': 36,colour: 'yellow'},
{'percent': 34,colour: 'orange'}
];


const donutData = countries.map((country, index) => {
  return {
    stroke: country.colour,
    dashoffset: 25 - countries.slice(0, index).reduce((a, b) => a + b.percent, 0),
    dashArray: [country.percent, 100 - country.percent]
  }
});
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<svg id="donut" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="3 3 36 36"></svg>';
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.querySelector('#donut').innerHTML= donutData.reduce((a, item) => {
  return a +
    `<circle 
   cx="21"
    cy="21"
    fill="transparent"
    r="15.91549430918954"
    stroke-width="2.3"
    stroke="${item.stroke}"
    stroke-dasharray="${item.dashArray[0]} ${item.dashArray[1]}"
    stroke-dashoffset="${item.dashoffset}"></circle>
`;
}, '')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/miladhi/1dxnkjht/1/

Above works fine, but try adding `stroke-linecap="round"` to the `<circle>` and it goes pare shaped, the strokes are on top of each other.

As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/miladhi/x8w4kgdv/.

I can understand the problem, but don't know how to add a little bit of margin between the strokes to avoid the ugly stacking.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: I'm not really sure if you are looking for this, but maybe you can try subtracting a litle percentage to each stroke (on `dashArray`): https://jsfiddle.net/3L728bmq/

Comment: One solution would be adding {'percent': 0,colour: 'red'} at the end of `countries` array. While the result can be allegedly more aesthetic, I I would not do it. For charts I would keep `stroke-linecap="butt"` Charts are visual tools and using `stroke-linecap="round"` may change the perception of the data.

Comment: @Shidersz, that won't work when the percents are lower than 2.5.

Comment: And what should happen if one or more of the amounts is less than the rounding radius.  What do you want to happen?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau that's the question I guess haha.

Comment: If you did this with paths rather than circle+stroke-dash, you could do a marker-end that wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @MichaelMullany would you show me an example please?

Comment: Added an example/answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

Just subtract the radius of the round endcaps (one for each end) from the dash length.

As long as the circle radius is not extremely small, the round caps should just touch each other neatly.

```js
const countries = [
{'percent': 10,colour: 'red'},
{'percent': 20,colour: 'blue'},
{'percent': 36,colour: 'yellow'},
{'percent': 34,colour: 'orange'}
];

const STROKE_WIDTH = 2.3;

const donutData = countries.map((country, index) => {
  // Subtract the radius of the round cap, twice.
  const dashLength = country.percent - STROKE_WIDTH;
  return {
    stroke: country.colour,
    dashoffset: 25 - countries.slice(0, index).reduce((a, b) => a + b.percent, 0),
    dashArray: [dashLength, 100 - dashLength]
  }
});
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<svg id="donut" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="3 3 36 36"></svg>';
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.querySelector('#donut').innerHTML= donutData.reduce((a, item) => {
  return a +
    `<circle 
   cx="21"
    cy="21"
    fill="transparent"
    r="15.91549430918954"
    stroke-width="${STROKE_WIDTH}"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    stroke="${item.stroke}"
    stroke-dasharray="${item.dashArray[0]} ${item.dashArray[1]}"
    stroke-dashoffset="${item.dashoffset}"></circle>
`;
}, '')
```

**Update**

A version which somewhat gracefully handles short line lengths.

```js
const countries = [
{'percent': 10, colour: 'red'},
{'percent': 20, colour: 'blue'},
{'percent': 36, colour: 'yellow'},
{'percent': 33, colour: 'orange'},
{'percent': 1,  colour: 'green'},
];

const STROKE_WIDTH = 2.3;

const donutData = countries.map((country, index) => {
  let dashLength, offsetAdjust, caps;
  if (country.percent >= STROKE_WIDTH) {
    // Subtract the radius of the round cap, twice.
    dashLength = country.percent - STROKE_WIDTH;
    offsetAdjust = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
    caps = "round";
  } else {
    dashLength = country.percent;
    offsetAdjust = 0;
    caps = "butt";
  }
  return {
    stroke: country.colour,
    dashoffset: 25 - countries.slice(0, index).reduce((a, b) => a + b.percent, 0) - offsetAdjust,
    dashArray: [dashLength, 100 - dashLength],
    caps: caps
  }
});
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<svg id="donut" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="3 3 36 36"></svg>';
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.querySelector('#donut').innerHTML= donutData.reduce((a, item) => {
  return a +
    `<circle 
   cx="21"
    cy="21"
    fill="transparent"
    r="15.91549430918954"
    stroke-width="${STROKE_WIDTH}"
    stroke-linecap="${item.caps}"
    stroke="${item.stroke}"
    stroke-dasharray="${item.dashArray[0]} ${item.dashArray[1]}"
    stroke-dashoffset="${item.dashoffset}"></circle>
`;
}, '')
```

Comment: LeBaue, thanks, but no. If you read the comments on my question, this answer is very limited, as soon as I change the percents, for any percent that's less than 2.3, it goes wrong

Comment: You never answered the question about how you wanted very small percentages to work.  One solution whould just be to not do the round caps for small values.  Any solution that adds caps onto the end of the dashes will change the effective length of the dashes and distort the relative percentages.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it with paths and markers. The trick is to use a marker start / marker end combo. The seeming overlap of the previous line is actually stuck onto the current line as a marker start.

```html
<svg width="600px" height="400px">
  <defs>
    <marker id="round-cap-blue" viewBox="0 0 1 1" 
        markerWidth="1" markerHeight="1"
        orient="auto" refX="0.5" refY="0.5">
      <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fill="blue"/>
    </marker>
    
        <marker id="round-cap-red" viewBox="0 0 1 1" 
        markerWidth="1" markerHeight="1"
        orient="auto" refX="0.5" refY="0.5">
      <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fill="red"/>
    </marker>
    
            <marker id="round-cap-green" viewBox="0 0 1 1" 
        markerWidth="1" markerHeight="1"
        orient="auto" refX="0.5" refY="0.5">
      <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fill="green"/>
    </marker>
    
    
    </defs>
  
  <g transform="translate(100,0)">
    
  <path fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="30" d="M 150 150
           A 100 100 0 0 0 50 50" marker-end="url(#round-cap-blue)"/>
  
   <path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="30" d="M 50 250
           A 100 100 0 0 0 150 150" marker-end="url(#round-cap-red)"/>
    
   <path fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="30" d="M 50 50
           A 100 100 0 0 0 50 250" marker-start="url(#round-cap-blue)" marker-end="url(#round-cap-green)"/>
    
    
  </g>
  
</svg>
```